# jQuery iterate array of arrays to output values as "parent-child"

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops

I have the following array:

```
 var elements = [
        { "a": [ "1", "2", ] }, 
        { "b": [ "1", "2", "3", "4" ] }, 
        { "c": [ "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" ] } 
    ];
```

How do I iterate the array in order to output the following:

a-1,a-2,b-1,b-2,b-3,b-4,c-1, c2 etc

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with  multi-pal nested loop  like below.

```js
var elements = [{
  "a": ["1", "2", ]
}, {
  "b": ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
}, {
  "c": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
}];


$.each(elements, function(i, data) {
  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    var value = val;
    $.each(value, function(i) {
      console.log(key + '-' + value[i]);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
var elements = [
    { "a": [ "1", "2", ] }, 
    { "b": [ "1", "2", "3", "4" ] }, 
    { "c": [ "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" ] } 
];
var result = '';
$.each(elements, function(i,e){
    $.each(e, function(ind, elem){
        $.each(elem, function(index, element){
            result += ind + '-' + element + ',';
        })
    })
})
result = result.substring(0, result.length-1);
console.log(result);
```